# Can't import a dmp file to oracle 12c database (imp-00037)

Tags: database, oracle-12c

I am trying to import a dmp file to my oracle 12c instance, while I used to do that without trouble I got a file which didn't work with both imp and impdp.

After long research without a result I could fine that there is a difference between this file (it is surely not corrupted) and my previous .dmp imports.

Those files that worked in the past I can see some information in their dmp headers files like :
"SYSTEM"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01"
11.01.00.00.00

But this one's header looks like :
TAPE
RAID
SPAD
SFMB
SSET 
SPAD 
VOLB
MSCI
MQCI

And so on.

When I try to import it I see these errors (using different formats of commands imp and impdp) :
ORA-39001
ORA-39000
ORA-39088
IMP-00037
IMP-00000

while my target db instance is 12c I am not sure what is the source version or which command took the file right now(can't reach the author currently), just I am sure it is not corrupted.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is MS Sql Server dump.   import in sql server.